# Reshaping and averaging matrices of training data

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, machine-learning

I am trying to "normalize" the shape of my training set
so that I can feed them into a Vanilla Neural Net.

The input always has the same number of "channels"/columns representing a feature
but has a varying number of rows for a given "y"

Is there a python or numpy or other utility that can take as input a matrix of 
dimension (m,n) of floats and stretch it to a given size of (m,o) where o > n
by inserting rows throughtout the new shape with values averaged

Example:
I have an array of shape (4,4) but require my array to be (7,4)

```
[
[1,1,1,1],
[2,2,2,2],
[1,1,1,1],
[4,4,4,4]
]
```

would become

```
[
[1,1,1,1],
[1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5],
[2,2,2,2],
[1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5],
[1,1,1,1],
[2.5,2.5,2.5,2.5],
[4,4,4,4]
]
```

Where the inserted rows have been averaged between the one before
and the one after 
Any ideas ?

Comment: That's not `4,7`, but `7,4`. Did you try 1D interpolation?

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to normalize this?  Is it 2d data, or do you need more training samples?

Comment: The data channels being recorded are only related to their adjacent rows as a simple average , as shown. The requirement is to end up with an array that contains an arbitrary number of rows by inserting no more than one row at a time and taking the average as indicated. In the case where we will need to add a single row we will choose to insert the row somewhere near the middle of the array. If we need to add many rows we will do this by iteration adding no more than 50% of the existing number of rows at a time until we reach the desired number of rows.  That is the requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to call insert_row(ar, positions) where ar is the 2d array you want to insert rows in and positions is a list of positions. It returns a numpy array with inserted rows.
try below code:

```
import numpy as np

ar = [
[1,1,1,1],
[2,2,2,2],
[1,1,1,1],
[4,4,4,4]
]


def insert_row(ar,positions):
    ar = np.array(ar)
    v = ar
    count = 0
    for i in positions:
            a = np.add(ar[i,:],ar[i+1,:])/2
            v = np.vstack([v[0:i+count+1,:],a,v[i+count+1:,:]])
            count+=1
    return v
```

output:

```
    print(insert_row(ar, [1,2]))

     [[ 1.   1.   1.   1. ]
     [ 2.   2.   2.   2. ]
     [ 1.5  1.5  1.5  1.5]
     [ 1.   1.   1.   1. ]
     [ 2.5  2.5  2.5  2.5]
     [ 4.   4.   4.   4. ]]

print(insert_row(ar, [0]))

[[ 1.   1.   1.   1. ]
 [ 1.5  1.5  1.5  1.5]
 [ 2.   2.   2.   2. ]
 [ 1.   1.   1.   1. ]
 [ 4.   4.   4.   4. ]]
```

Comment: Thanks @jimidime, was thinking that this sort of functionality already existed in one of the many python libraries. See the comment above regarding where we wish to insert the new rows and average depending on how many rows we need to insert to get to the desired dimensions.So the code you posted doesnt quite handle arbitrary number of rows being inserted.